# get URL Answer with curl or json

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I need to get the answer of a page.
The url looks like this:

```
sp2.looki.de/index.php?page=newsysview&cid=48713&ppx=71&ppy=32&cid=48713&tcv=1355771664807&_=_585_204
```

The Answer I get looks like this:

> {"module":"system","error":[],"syslist":{"15":{"con1":"0","con2":"0","kgm":"257506","kgk":"317370","kgt":"10300255","ppx":"71","ppy":"32","ppz":"15","pname":"Ckaleme","playerid":"5428","flag":"1","noob":"85315748","sperrflag":"-1","nick":"S7alker","tag":"-R-","pid":"707","allianzid":"707","inaktiv":1,"platz0":"82","punkte0":"187044480","platz1":"196","punkte1":"21326785","platz2":"87","punkte2":"105724483","platz3":"69","punkte3":"59993212","oldlogin":null,"nickdays":"0","isnoob":false}},"tflist":[],"ppx":71,"ppy":32,"allianzid":3225,"allianzpid":3225,"debug":{"parsetime":[{"name":"Start","parsetime_complete":"0.000","parsetime_last":"0.000"},{"name":"Ende","parsetime_complete":"0.014","parsetime_last":"0.014"}],"parsetime_total":"0.014","querytime":0.0026}}

I've tried with CURL, file_get_contents and so on ... but the answer was just an

> www:redirect

---

Code edited....no result

```
$data  = "http://some.site.de/index.php?page=newsysview&cid=48713&ppx=50&ppy=50&cid=48713&tcv=1355426935816&_=_552_140";
$ch = curl_init($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

The Page --> http://sp2.looki.de/index.php?page=newsysview&cid=48713&ppx=50&ppy=50&cid=48713&tcv=1355511915397&_=_482_292

### I get a json as answer

So ... after some days of tryin' I have no ideas anymore.
No idea, how to login there, to jump to a specified page and read the json from there.
maybe someone has an great idea to help me out.
LogIn Page is here --> http://sp2.looki.de/

:'(

### Edit 2

I stuck ....

I've the following code now ...

```
$data1 = "http://sp2.looki.de/index.php?page=newsysview&cid=48713&ppx=50&ppy=50&cid=48713&tcv=1355511915397&_=_482_292";
$ch = curl_init ($data1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
```

in my `var_dump($data)` it's just an `{"www-redirect": "/"}`

WHY?

oh .... hint:

the original address is: http://sp2.looki.de/index.php?page=gui&cid=666#nothing

the address in $data1 seems to be an ajax request.

Comment: `some.site.de` does not exist (at least according to my local DNS).

Comment: You need to enable `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` settings to follow the redirects then. I believe it's all in the [**PHP MANUAL**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), or just visit the adress and see where it leads?

Comment: @adeno that sounds like an answer, not a comment, to me ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak ;) ... sure ... the Domain is'nt the right one.

Comment: my Code now: > $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_exec($ch); ... no result, just an {"www-redirect": "/"}
curl_close($ch);

Comment: possible duplicate of [php cURL POST how to follow location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607139/php-curl-post-how-to-follow-location)

Comment: @ShaoKhan please put your code in the question itself, will be easier to read :-) Replace `false` by `true` anyway.

Comment: The follow location parameter is disabled, change 'false' to 'true' or just the number '1', and it will follow the redirects until it finds a page.

Comment: @Ninsuo: done ... thanks ... update code in my question above.

Comment: Apart from  my answer below about Location and Referer, you need to add "curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) ;" if you want to retrieve the content, maybe you have it disabled by default.

Comment: Do you get that JSON string in your browser when just visiting the link directly, or does it take some user interaction etc. to get that result ?

Comment: @adeneo question above updated

Comment: Visiting that link gives a plain {"www-redirect": "/"}, so maybe you must authenticate against the website or simulate a previous session... that curl code is clearly correct and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @MarcosBesteiroLópez how to simulate ?

Comment: Visiting the link, I get the same as Marcos, just the JSON string `{"www-redirect": "/"}`, which is what you are getting when using cURL, sort of makes sense. Do you log in to see the result in your browser?

Comment: uhm ... Yes .... it means, no chance for me ?

Comment: It is , but more complex, take a look at PHP cookiejar, and auth with curl, for example, to start  http://www.kunaal84.com/blog/2008/05/30/save-login-info-in-a-cookie-using-curl-php/

Comment: What Marcos said! You'll have to submit the login POST request with cURL to be able to get the content.

Comment: how can i check the login was successful ?

Comment: @ShaoKhan if you just want to grab everything once, you can try using the cookies from your browser and pass them via `CURLOPT_COOKIE`. But if you need to request the data regularly, you'll have to write the authentication login for curl to log in and then grab the data.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have Follow Location active in your curl request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Otherwise you are forcing it to not follow the "Location:" headers

http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php

Additionally, maybe the website doesn't allow direct query of that URL, try to trick it using the "Referer" value of curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://some.site.de/');
```